# How to build simple accordion using only specific table rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML table listing various items. Every `<tr>` has a unique `title` element, but some items are related and those rows share the same title. I'm trying to write jQuery code that would parse this table and convert only those items with the same title into a simple accordion, then inject a new clickable row just above them that will use that shared title as a content, and toggle those related items on click.

This is an example table, before conversion where "Orange" items are related:

```
<table>
    <tr title="Banana">
        <td>Document 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="Apple">
        <td>Document 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="Orange">
        <td>Document 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="Orange">
        <td>Document 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="Orange">
        <td>Document 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="Lemon">
        <td>Document 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="Cherry">
        <td>Document 7</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is what I'm trying to convert this table to. Basically I'm hiding related items and I'm using a newly created row above them to show/hide:

```
<table>
    <tr title="Banana">
        <td>Document 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="Apple">
        <td>Document 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="Orange">
        <td>Orange (click to toggle)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="Orange" style="display:none;">
        <td>Document 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="Orange" style="display:none;">
        <td>Document 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="Orange" style="display:none;">
        <td>Document 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="Lemon">
        <td>Document 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="Cherry">
        <td>Document 7</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Note 1:** The title can be anything. I'm just using "Orange" as an example here, but in reality the title can be even multiple words.

**Note 2:** Related items will be stacked one after another.

What would be the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: would all of the items you want to collapse be one after the other? i.e. in your example you want to collapse `orange`, but if there were another `Lemon` after the current one, would you also want to collapse those?

Comment: Yes @Jhecht, that is correct. Items will be stacked. I also updated my question to reflect this comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can start from here

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var titles_arr = [] , create_list = [];
  $('tr[title]').each(function(){
   var title = $(this).attr('title').trim();
    if($.inArray( title , titles_arr) > -1){
      if($.inArray( title , create_list) <= -1){
       create_list.push(title);
      }
    }else{
     titles_arr.push(title);
    }
  });
  //console.log(create_list[0]);
  for(var i = 0 ; i < create_list.length ; i++){
   var newtrTitle = create_list[i];
    var html = '<tr title="'+newtrTitle+'" class="clcToggle"><td>'+newtrTitle+' (Click To Toggle)</td></tr>';
    $(html).insertBefore('tr[title="'+newtrTitle+'"]:eq(0)').promise().done(function(){
     $('tr[title="'+newtrTitle+'"]').not(':eq(0)').hide();
    });
    
  }
  
 
  
  $('#MainTable').on('click', '.clcToggle',function(){
   var title = $(this).attr('title').trim();
   $('tr[title="'+title+'"]').not(':eq(0)').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="MainTable">
    <tr title="Banana">
        <td>Document 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="Apple">
        <td>Document 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="Orange">
        <td>Document 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="Orange">
        <td>Document 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="Orange">
        <td>Document 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="Lemon">
        <td>Document 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="Lemon">
        <td>Document 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="Cherry">
        <td>Document 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="Cherry">
        <td>Document 8</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

> Note : this code will work just fine if you have the same tr title behind
>   each other .. need a little bit of work to arrange them if its
>   randomly arranged

Comment: Wow @Mohamed-Yousef, this is great. Only thing with these randomly arranged items is that when displayed they will show in original position instead of grouped with other related items. But, as I mentioned, all related items in my table will be grouped together so please there's no need to update your code. This is already very impressive. I'll test this with my actual data now.

Comment: @Giuliano I did and remove the updated part  :) .. and hope my code will work with you

Answer (score 1):

If I can assume that all item of the same type is grouped together:

```
// Step 1: Code to add an extra row if there are multiple occurrences of an item
// This is not dynamic yet
if($("tr[title='Orange']").length>1){ // if there is more than one occurance
   $("tr[title='Orange']").first().before('<tr title="Orange"><td>Orange (click to toggle)</td></tr>')
}

    // Step 2: Loop through the items to make the above code dynamic
var ftypes = [];
$("table tr").each(function(idx)){
// get one of each type of fruit
if(ftypes.indexOf($(this).attr('title'))<0) ftypes.push($(this).attr('title'));
});

ftypes.forEach(function(fruit){
// if each fruit have more than one occurrence then add a row above
   if($("tr[title='"+fruit+"']").length>1){
       $("tr[title='"+fruit+"']").first().before('<tr title="'+fruit+'"><td>Orange (click to toggle)</td></tr>')
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @blokeish, I should have clarified in my question that title can be anything. In this example it's "Orange" but in reality it can be anything. Is it possible to modify your code to look for repeating titles?

Comment: Hi Giuliano, step 1 code is just the example code to show whats being done. Step 2 is the complete code. First it gets all the unique titles in the table and stores it in an array then in the second loop it goes through each item and then see if there are multiple occurrences of that. If yes then it adds an extra row to the top. You will have to implement the accordion feature, select siblings with the same title and hide/show.

Answer (score 1):

I added an extra row to double check that it was working correctly.

I hope the comments help enough.

```js
function click_handler(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  //I am too lazy to write $(this) over and over again
  $('tr[title="' + $this.prop('title') + '"]').not($this).toggle();
  //First Part: gets all TR elements with same title
  //Next Part: but not this element
  //Toggle their visibility;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  var prev; //Previous Element.
  var prev_i = 0; //previous level.
  $('tr').each(function(i, el) {
    el = $(el);
    if (prev != null) {
      //So we are not at the first element.
      if (prev.prop('title') == el.prop('title')) {
        //The previous title and the current el title are the same.
        if (prev_i == 0) {
          prev.text(prev.text() + "(click to toggle)");
          //If we are at previous level 0, meaning we have not encountered this portion of the loop before, we need to add the "click to toggle" text.
          prev.on('click', click_handler.bind(prev));
          //Add the click_handler, bound to the previous element (first).
        }

        el.hide(); //Hide any not-first element with the same title

        ++prev_i;
      } else {
        prev_i = 0;
        //If the titles are different, we reset the previous level.
      }

    } //end prev!=null
    prev = el;
    //set previous element
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr title="Banana">
    <td>Document 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr title="Apple">
    <td>Document 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr title="Orange">
    <td>Orange</td>
  </tr>
  <tr title="Orange">
    <td>Document 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr title="Orange">
    <td>Document 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr title="Orange">
    <td>Document 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr title="Lemon">
    <td>Document 6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr title="Lemon">
    <td>Document 7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr title="Cherry">
    <td>Document 8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```